# I cant start context broker due to "error starting REST interface"

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

When I enter the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/contextBroker start
```

I get the following output:

```
Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No such file or directory
pidfile not found                                          [FAILED]
```

I have two machines where I am practising with context broker and I havent touched the second one in days after I succesfully installed it and managed to receive a post message from a remote weather station.
I see that the directory /var/run/contextBroker/ is actually empty

**What should I do to fix this now? reinstal context broker or?**
**So is this somehow my fault and how do I prevent in the future?** I dont want this happening when my app goes live.

**EDIT1: the orion version is 0.20.0**

**EDIT2:** I just reinstalled contextBroker and I get the same problem. What are exectly the contents of that directory? Could I maybe just create the files inside?

**EDIT3:** Since running contextBroker as a system service still yields an unsuccessful start, I also attempted to run it symply by typing:

`contextBroker` in the command line, after which I get the following response

```
INFO@14:03:03  contextBroker.cpp[1346]: Orion Context Broker is running
[root@localhost DevF12]# INFO@14:03:03  MongoGlobal.cpp[181]: Successful connection to database
INFO@14:03:03  contextBroker.cpp[1157]: Connected to mongo at localhost:orion
INFO@14:03:03  MongoGlobal.cpp[499]: Database Operation Successful ({ conditions.type: "ONTIMEINTERVAL" })
FATAL@14:03:03  rest.cpp[1013]: Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)
```

**EDIT4:** Ok so I tried `ps aux | grep contextBroker` and the result is:

```
494       2196  0.0  7.0 688696 135116 ?       Ssl  Apr21   0:02 /usr/bin/contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion
root      7299  0.0  6.9 621052 134440 ?       Ssl  04:21   0:00 contextBroker -port 1028
root      8870  0.0  0.0 103256   848 pts/0    S+   08:51   0:00 grep contextBroker
```

but there simply isnt anything in `/var/run/contextBroker/`
Should I put contextBroker.pid by myself? and if so, what should the contents be?

**EDIT5:** I just ran `netstat -ntlpd | grep 1026` and the output is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1026                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2196/contextBroker  
tcp        0      0 :::1026                     :::*                        LISTEN      2196/contextBroker
```

So I guess nothing else but contextBroker is listening?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the Orion version you have installed, please? Typically, doing `contextBroker --version` or `rpm -q contextBroker`. Thanks!

Comment: posted edited- the orion version is 0.20.0

Comment: do `ps aux | grep contextBroker` and see if you get any contextBroker running at all. If you do, then kill it and start over.

Comment: The `(error starting REST interface)` message use to mean some problem in the network interface. Please, check that no other process is listening at the same port (typically running `netstat -ntlpd | grep 1026`)

Comment: As you can see, there are two instances of contextBroker running. Kill them both with something like `sudo kill -9 <pid>`, where <pid> is the number in the second column of the process you want to kill. Then you will be able to run it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record (it was answered in the comments).

The message `FATAL@XX:XX:XX  rest.cpp[1013]: Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)` means that there is a networking problem. Usually an interface or an already used port.

The usual cause is that there is another instance of Orion running (as a service, for example).

The way to solve it would be to kill the process entirely. Show all Orion processes with `ps aux | grep contextBroker` and issue a `kill -9 <pid>`, where `<pid>` is the process number (the second column of the output of the ps command).